# How to use C# to display Registry results on Rich Text Box?

Tags: c#, registry, richtextbox

I have a program which is able to retrieve various registry values using C# codes which was compiled and created using VS 2010.

However the problem arises when I tried to display the results retrieved from the Windows Registry into a rich text box within a form.

The form only shows 1 line which is the last value in the Array that contains the results.

Please do give some advice on the codes. Thanks!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace Syscrawl
{
public partial class FTK_Menu_Browsing_History : Form
{
    public FTK_Menu_Browsing_History()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void buttonFileHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        FTK_Menu_File_History mfh = new FTK_Menu_File_History();
        mfh.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonEncryptedFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        FTK_Menu_Encrypted_Files mef = new FTK_Menu_Encrypted_Files();
        mef.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonRecentlyAccessedFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        FTK_Menu_Recently_Accessed_Files mraf = new FTK_Menu_Recently_Accessed_Files();
        mraf.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonRegistryHistory_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        FTK_Menu_Registry_History mrh = new FTK_Menu_Registry_History();
        mrh.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonMainMenu_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Menu m = new Menu();
        m.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void buttonLogOut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Syscrawl_Login sl = new Syscrawl_Login();
        sl.ShowDialog();
        this.Close();
    }

    private void FTK_Menu_Browsing_History_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RegistryKey rk = Registry.CurrentUser;

            rk = rk.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\TypedURLs", 
    false);
            PrintKeys(rk);
            rk.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception MyError)
        {
            richTextBoxBrowsing.Text="An error has occurred: " + MyError.Message;
        }
    }

    void PrintKeys(RegistryKey rk)
    {
        if (rk == null)
        {
            richTextBoxBrowsing.Text="Couldn't open the desired subkey.";
            return;
        }

        richTextBoxBrowsing.Text = "Subkeys of " + rk.Name;

        try
        {
            string[] valnames = rk.GetValueNames();
            int i = 0;

            foreach (string s in valnames)
            {
                string val = (string)rk.GetValue(valnames[i++]);

        richTextBoxBrowsing.Text="-----------------------------------------------";
                richTextBoxBrowsing.Text=s + " contains " + val;
            }
        }

        catch (Exception MyError)
        {
            richTextBoxBrowsing.Text = "An errors has occurred: " + MyError.Message;
        }
    }

    private void richTextBoxBrowsing_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
   }
 }
```

Comment: One suggestion: when you post code, include only the relevant parts (the Click events weren't related to the textbox issue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By saying:

```
richTextBoxBrowsing.Text=
```

in each iteration of your loop, you keep on overwriting the text. So only the last call to the Text property gets printed.

You need to set the `richTextBoxBrowsing.TextMode` property to multiline, and then instead call:

```
richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText(s + " contains " + val + "\n");
```

Oh, and by the way, use: `string val = rk.GetValue(s).ToString();`

so you can remove the `int i = 0;` declaration

Answer (score 1):

- Confirm that you set
  `richTextBoxBrowsing.TextMode` to
  `MultiLine`
- Change `richTextBoxBrowsing.Text+=s + " contains " + val;` in foreach loop
- Use [`Debug.WriteLine`](https://web.archive.org/web/20150109120233/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/csharpfaq/archive/2006/10/09/how-do-i-send-out-simple-debug-messages-to-help-with-my-debugging_3f00_.aspx) to debug return
  value

Comment: Could you provide some codes for the multiline? and debug? Thanks.

Comment: @JavaNoob I've updated the post and link Debug.WriteLine. This might be helpful. And I think if you do first two steps from above your problem will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText(...)`

Answer (score 1):

You're changing the entire contents with each call, instead of appending to it:

```
richTextBoxBrowsing.Text=s + " contains " + val;
```

should be

```
richTextBoxBrowsing.AppendText(s+" contains " + val+Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: It shows all the results now but its all clumped up...How can I make to show line by line? Thanks.

Comment: @JavaNoob: edited to add the newline code: You add Environment.NewLine at the end of the string you want to append, and that will use the system's new line character

Answer (score 0):

I think your loop is not correct.

In `_void PrintKeys()_` your Loop overwerites your `RichTextBox.Text-Value` try something like:

```
String temp = "-----------------------------------------------";
foreach (string s in valnames)
{
    String val = (String)rk.GetValue(valnames[i++]);                
    temp=temp+s + " contains " + val;
}

RichTextBox.text = temp;
```

Comment: You should use a StringBuilder rather than repeatedly appending text to a string.

Comment: I know, but as it was often discussed before, I depends on how much Strings you really concatinating. In this little example, I think it shouldn't matter.